# The instance of entity type 'Game' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am unit testing an application I made with an in-memory database using Entity Framework Core but I am running into a problem with one of my functions. I have so far tested getting a game by Id (it works), adding a game to the collection (it works too) and updating a game in the collection (it doesn't work).

The function code:

```
 [TestMethod()]
        public async Task UpdateGameAsyncTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            await CreateDb();

            GameDto gameDto = new GameDto()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Team1 = "PSG",
                Team2 = "AZ",
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            //Act
            var id = await _gameService2.UpdateGameAsync(gameDto);
            var game = await _gameService2.GetGameAsync(id);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("AZ", game.Team1);
        }
```

UpdateGameAsync() in my service layer:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateGameAsync(GameDto game)
        {
            var gameEntity = game.ToEntity();

            return await _gameRepository.UpdateGameAsync(gameEntity);
        }
```

UpdateGameAsync() in my repository layer:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateGameAsync(Game game)
        {
            if (game.Result != null)
            {
                if (game.Result.Length == 3 && game.Result.Substring(1, 1) == "-")
                {
                    game.typeResult = await CheckTypeResult(game.Result);
                }
            }
            _dbContext.Games.Update(game);

            return await AutoSaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

CreateDb():

```
public async Task CreateDb()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StrikeNetDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
                .Options;

            var dbContext = new StrikeNetDbContext(options);

            if (await dbContext.Games.CountAsync() <= 0)
            {
                Game g1 = new Game()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Team1 = "FCB",
                    Team2 = "BVB",
                    Date = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
                Game g2 = new Game()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Team1 = "PSG",
                    Team2 = "PSV",
                    Date = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
                Game g3 = new Game()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Team1 = "Ajax",
                    Team2 = "Feyenoord",
                    Date = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
                dbContext.Games.Add(g1);
                dbContext.Games.Add(g2);
                dbContext.Games.Add(g3);
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            var gameRepository = new GameRepository(dbContext);
            _gameService2 = new GameService(gameRepository);
        }
```

When running the test I am running into the error: "The instance of entity type 'Game' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 2}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."

For comparing purposes, here is the adding function that DOES work:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public async Task AddGameAsyncTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            await CreateDb();

            GameDto game = new GameDto()
            {
                Team1 = "Juve",
                Team2 = "Real",
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            //Act
            var id = await _gameService2.AddGameAsync(game);
            var expected = await _gameService2.GetGameAsync(id);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("Juve", expected.Team1);
        }
```

I have tried several things that answers to similar questions suggested but none of them work for me. I do have my repository en service scoped in Startup.cs, and detaching the entities in the createdb() function als doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any other idea?

Comment: You show the add method, why not the update method? After all, there's the issue.

Comment: @GertArnold The update function is the first code block

Comment: Not `UpdateGameAsync`. That's where it's happening.

Comment: @GertArnold I see what you mean now, I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's come from your `UpdateGameAsync` method. If you call EF `Update` inside, as the documentation says, you try to track the entity

[Begins tracking the given entity in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2402ae49f52753262db1485bf3d5b68f43776c5b/src/EFCore/DbSet.cs#L231)

But, i think your entity is already tracked, because i feel like you use the same dbContext in `CreateDb`, and this line begin the tracking of your entity:

`dbContext.Games.Add(g2);`

You can check if your entity is tracked in your repository:

`_context.Games.Local.Any(g => g.Id == entity.Id)`

If it's already tracked, you don't need to call EF `Update()`.

By the way, if your real case do not use the same DbContext for data initialization and data read, i recommand to use another context to be sure that's work as you want.

Comment: Creating a new instance of dbcontext in my test indeed worked like I wanted it too. Thanks!